# copy git repo between servers, but allow local change

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo on server A with the main version of a package that needs to stay there (note: all gits here are GitLab).

I need to duplicate this repo to server B for an operational use of the package.

What I want is:

To have the repo on server B automatically updated when changes are made to the repo on server A (so like a mirror), but at the same time be able to do some commits only on server B (add new files for operational use in my company that I don't want to appear on server A).

I have tried to have different origins so we can pull from the different origins and then push only to server B when I make changes to the files that only exist on server B, but this is not really convincing and requires manual updating of server B when A is updated. This could still be a solution, but I'm having problems with conflicts and a clean example of how to achieve this would be welcome.

Submodules is not a solution either, as the git on server B should be a clean R library directory with the added files directly inside.

What I would like is some kind of fork between servers with, if possible, automatic update from the original repo (but I imagine automation is hard because of conflicts, so I can live with manual update).

Thanks for the help

Comment: What kind of conflicts do you get? I would set up two projects, one with the repo on server A that you add your changes to and another projects which uses server A's repo like a library and only contains patches for changes which are applied after checkout or something similar. What are the differences like? Only additional files or elaborate changes to certain files?